# Porque o request.ok dá False neste worten scraper?

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_page(url):
    resposta = requests.get(url)
    print(resposta.ok)

def main():
    url = 'https://www.worten.pt/search?query='
    get_page(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Estou a fazer um scraper da worten e quando tento dar o `#resposta.ok#` recebo a informação `"False"` o que significa que o servidor não respondeu, alguém sabe porquê?

Answer (score -1):

Copiei o texto da resposta da requisição usando o seguinte código:

```py
print(resposta.text)
```

Coloquei em um arquivo .html e abri no browser. O resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: Imagem com o resultado do texto da resposta do código informado.]

Como pode ver, aparentemente o site colocou uma etapa de verificação contra bots e por isso o resposta.ok é False.

Comment: Hum okay muito obrigado, ainda sou muito leigo no assunto. Existe alguam forma de passar por este captcha?